# Doble validación con form request

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un form request que valida si una matricula es única en la tabla estación. Está de esta forma:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'matricula' => unique:estacion,matricula,
        
    ];
}
```

Funciona bien, pero tengo varias estaciones y cada estación puede tener una matricula igual y esto es válido.

Por ejemplo La estacion1 tiene la matricula 001 y la estacion3 tambien puede tener la matricula 001.

Me gustaría saber como puedo validar que la matricula no se repita, pero solo dentro de una estación.

Es decir que la matricula 001 no pueda estar duplicada en la estacion1, pero que si pueda duplicarse en la estacion2.

Tengo una tabla de matriculas que contiene todas las matriculas, lo único que diferencia cada numero de matricula es la estacion_id que es la llave foránea que relaciona a las tablas. La relación es estacion has many matriculas.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con el form request? Que solución me aconsejan?

Comment: ¿Entonces la misma estación se puede repetir N cantidad de veces en la misma tabla?

Comment: Si. Tengo una tabla llamara matriculas. Lo único que diferencia a una de otra es el Id de la estación. @BetaM

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de relación estamos hablando entre las tablas?

Comment: La relación es estacion has many matriculas.

Comment: Seria bueno editar tu pregunta y agregar esos detalles ahi para no dejarlo como comentario

Comment: @JuanRivera tienes razón, ya la edite.